# Override html.tpl.php per node type does not work

Tags: theming, nodes, caching

I saw that this was asked few times before, and I tried the answers, and I tried modifying the answers, yet nothing.

Case:
I have [**Advanced Forum**](https://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) installed, and I am using [HTML5 Application Cache](https://drupal.org/project/appcache) (**appcache**) (don't you dear to run away now!).

Obviously I need to turn **appcache** off when surffing forums, and I managed to make custom `html.tpl.html` for `/forum` and `/forums`, so when I am looking forum list and topic list I won't get cached.

But then:
When I am looking at forum topic, it is a post ofc, and post type (machine type is `forum`) and I have defined in `template.php`:

```
$node = menu_get_object();

if ($node && $node->nid) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestion'][] = 'html__' . $node->type;
}
```

and it won't make change.

So I am able to change `html.tpl.php` for path but not for node type.

Help me please and correct my knowledge for making such things.

Thanks for all!!!
(btw i dont need a lesson of **appcache**, sincerely if you have manifest = x.appcache" in your html tag it will cache it, even if it's in network section)

Comment: Why are you trying to override html.tpl.php per node type? Suppose you have a node type called `questions`, and another one called `answers`. All you need is page--questions.tpl.php or page--answers.tpl.php, respectively. You need 1 - if it's D6, and 2 - if D7.

Comment: ye, ive done so, i am using advanced forum, and i can see node type would be forum (node-type-forum) and i have tpl like this html--forum.tpl.php

Comment: Oh i got it now, i need to overdrive html.tpl.php bcuz i need to disable appcache in forum topics. And dont give me any lesson about appcache, once it is in html tag it will cache it. respectively.

Comment: I can't think of a use case where you'd need to override html.tpl.php except for once in the theme but variations on that per node type don't make sense. If you are trying to add css or JS or other head tasks just for your content type (just a guess), don't hack on html.tpl.php, rather use preprocess functions in your theme's template.php with conditionals. I can see overriding page.tpl.php which can be done with a preprocess function though.

Comment: Danny, as i wrote, i am managing appcache with this and if you have appcache with forum, it wont work as you want, since if some one comments you cant see the new comment since that page is cached. Appcache is still so beta'ish that it needs some forking to be effective way to build offline cache. And i have so much info/traffic that i need to cache some things. And im using adaptive theme, where we created our own html.tpl.php and now i have custom html.tpl.php for node types of forum. And it worked after all, i just had i typo on it ;_;

Comment: I am closing this, since the OP in [a comment](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112143/override-html-tpl-php-per-node-type-does-not-work#comment134517_112183) says "i had `$vars` instead of `$variables`."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need different template for this. 
you can set variable in preprocess function and print it.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html (&$variables, $hook) 
  $node = menu_get_object();
  $dont_cache = array('some_type');
  if (!empty($node->nid) && in_array($node->type, $dont_cache)) {//check if it is node and if it shouldnt be cached
    $variables['appcache'] = '';
  }
  else {
    $variables['appcache'] = 'manifest = x.appcache';//put your value here
  } 
 }
```

and then print $appcache in you html.tpl.php

Comment: And i tried this, this does not work at all.

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? 
where did u put your_theme_name_preprocess_html ? did you rename your_theme_name to you theme name? and did you put it in template.php? is that function called?

Comment: oh i got it now, a little late. This only applies in nodes. I need to make it like this:

Comment: if (!empty($node->nid){//check if it is node and if it shouldnt be cached
    $variables['appcache'] = 'manifest="appcache.manifest"';
  }
  elseif (!empty($node->nid) && in_array($node->type, $dont_cache))  {
    
  } 
 }

Comment: No, it does not cache anything now. With your code. are you online so we could chat in i dunno maybe skype

Comment: just bumping so you will wake up

Comment: It seems like preprocess var's wont be moved into tpl files. so i need to make 2 tpl file, another with and another without.

Comment: for me it all works fine. if you set  $variables['appcache'] 
then in html.tpl.php $appcache is available. just put die(); in your your_theme_name_preprocess_html  and see if it called. maybe you need to clear theme cache

Comment: nope. it doesnt work for me. even i cleared cache. I have print $appcache; in my html tag and i used your code, it doesnt cache anything now.

Comment: probably you doing something wrong check how is it done check these link maybe it will helo more[link](http://highrockmedia.com/blog/drupal-7-preprocess-tricks-tips-themer)
[link](https://drupal.org/node/223430)

Comment: i had $vars instead of $variables...